# Minimum Levenshtein distance in list

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

how to calculate the minimum distance between a set of rows the input is supplied with lines (25 in total), you need to find the lines with the minimum distance and specify the distance itself. what I do

```
file = open('input.txt')
bio = []
for i in range(N):
    a = file.readline().strip()
    bio.append(a)
distance = 0
min_d = 0
dop_l_1 = []
dop_l_2 = []
for i in bio:
    list_d = []
    for j in range(len(bio)):
        distance = distance_1(i, bio[j])
        list_d.append(distance)
    res = nsmallest(2, list_d)[1]
    ind = list_d.index(res)
    dop_l_1.append((i, bio[ind]))
    dop_l_2.append(res)
    if min(dop_l_2) == 1:
        break
mini = min(dop_l_2)
m = dop_l_2.index(mini)
m_2 = dop_l_1[m]
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
print(bio.index(m_2[0]) + 1, bio.index(m_2[1]) + 1, mini, file=fout)
```

distance_1 - the function calculates the distance between two rows

my implementation is too slow is there a way to find from a set of rows two that have the minimum distance, except by passing through all the rows in turn

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with C++?

Comment: One thing you can do is take advantage of the fact the `distance(A->B)` is always equal to `distance(B->A)` and not bother to calculate distances between row-pairs that you already calculated the distance for using the opposite ordering.  A second thing might be to find a more efficient Levenshtein algorithm; it's not clear which one you are using but some of them are much more efficient than others:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: I didn't think of that, so I'll try to write it. if you have an idea how to write it, I will be happy.